# header information using clang

Tags: c++, clang++

I am new to clang libtooling. I am working on one project where I need to extract info about function/methods like function name, return type, parameter type, class/namespace it belongs to, file name(there would be multiple files in the module) and header file dependencies. I am able to retrieve almost all the info I am seeking for but couldn't able to extract header file info. I guess it is something related to `clang::HeaderSearch` but how to create object of this type as this required `(std::shared_ptr< HeaderSearchOptions > HSOpts, SourceManager &SourceMgr, DiagnosticsEngine &Diags, const LangOptions &LangOpts, const TargetInfo *Target)` all these as parameter and I am not sure what all these about. Thanks in advance.